# How to test this class?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I need idea how to tests this class? I should test when Bufferedreader return other value than null? Or test when queue is empty?

```java
public class DataFromTxtFile {

    private Queue<String> myLines;

    public DataFromTxtFile(){
        this.myLines = new ArrayDeque<>();
    }

    public void readDataFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                myLines.offer(line);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getLine() {
        if(myLines.size() == 0) return "";
        return myLines.poll();
    }

public boolean isFileNullOrEmpty(File file){
        if(file == null || file.length()==0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ok, this is my 3 example tests which i created. This is good way to create unit tests for this method? Currently, im trying to test my other methods. Can you give me advice?

```java
public class DataFromTxtFileTest {

    private DataFromTxtFile dataFromTxtFile;
    private ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    private File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("example.txt").getFile());

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        dataFromTxtFile = new DataFromTxtFile();
    }

    @Test
    public void isFileNull(){
        File file = null;
        assertTrue(dataFromTxtFile.isFileNullOrEmpty(file));
    }

    @Test
    public void isFileEmpty() throws IOException {
        File file = temporaryFolder.newFile("testFile.txt");
        assertTrue(dataFromTxtFile.isFileNullOrEmpty(file));
    }

    @Test
    public void isCorrectFile() throws IOException {
        assertFalse(dataFromTxtFile.isFileNullOrEmpty(file));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please first try to find it yourself.

Comment: A good test tests every possible condition, especially corner cases. Be creative ! For example: what if the file doesn't exist ? Or the file is empty or not-readable. Then 'does it do it's job' (add a client test class DataFromTxtFileTest executing your new methods in the right order).

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you show us the unit tests you've written so far?

Comment: Okay, I've been editing the main post, can you tell me that its good way to create unit tests?

Comment: For a better overview you could have a look at https://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html but that just as a sidenote. The rest ok for a start. I'm not a big unit test guru myself. Just make sure you get all possible Inputs for all methods.
When you test readDataFromFile() use @Test(expected = IOException.class), when you expect an exception to happen, because your class under test has a throws statement.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should think about all possible test cases.
Since file is your only input, you should test both methods with all possible variations of that input to get all wanted outcomes (including exceptions).

- null input
- empty file
- correct file
- file with special characters
- different encodings

For every input there should be one output.
This is a very simple example and with a little research on junit you should be able to implement the test cases on your own. You might want to post your test methods for further questions.
Here is a little article that might get you started:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html
But this doesn't go very deep.

Have in mind that you can test whether a exception occurs with method annotations like

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
```